# SPARQL - Inverse Path of dynamic discovered relationship

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, skos

I have a Graph Database that implements only one side of relationships in the model structures. For instance, All Broader relationships are mapped as `skos:broader`. All Narrower relationships are mapped as `^skos:broader` (for whatever reasons they chose to do this, I have no control over this.)

I am trying to write a SPARQL Query that delivers something like

> Query for all relationships of a given IRI, and their associated values.
>   The goal is to make a JSON or XML Representation of all the content.

Here is what I have working.

```
  PREFIX  skosxl: <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#>
  PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
  PREFIX  skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
  PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

  select  ?relation ?value 
  where 
  {
       <CONCEPT_URI> ?r ?c    

       OPTIONAL {  
           ?r rdfs:label|skosxl:prefLabel ?l 
       }

       OPTIONAL {  
           ?c skosxl:prefLabel/skosxl:literalForm|skosxl:literalForm ?d .
        }

        BIND ( if (bound(?d), ?d, ?c) as ?value )
        BIND ( if (bound(?l), ?l, strafter(?r, '#')) as ?relation ) 

   }
```

This works to give me all the concept relationships (IE: Broader), but it does not give me the narrower items (IE: ^broader).

Is there anyway that I can extend this generic query to produce the inverses of any relationships it finds, as well? I Tried simply adding the `^` to the `?r` in the `where` clause but it does not like that syntactically.

Thanks,

Comment: Let's suppose that `:father :hasSon :Son`. For `:father`, you need something like `"has son" "son"`. What do you need for `:son`? What the inverse property name should be?

Comment: `if (bound(?d), ?d, ?c)` is `coalesce(?d, ?c)`.  Similarly, `if (bound(?l), ?l, strafter(?r, '#'))` is `coalesce(?l, strafter(?r, '#'))`.

Comment: Why should this give you the narrower items? You have the URI in subject position, you'd need the same in object position, i.e. `{SELECT ... where { {<CONCEPT_URI> ?r ?c } UNION {?c ?r <CONCEPT_URI> } ... }` Note, property paths can't have variables, thus, something like `?p|^?p` isn't possible. There are some workarounds like wildcard patterns, but not needed here

Comment: By the way, in the path `?c skosxl:prefLabel/skosxl:literalForm|skosxl:literalForm ?d .` the alternative `skosxl:literalForm|skosxl:literalForm` is probably not what you wanted. Be careful with the prefixes...